# How to combine two variable in ascx file

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I want to use javascript to open a window when people click on the name.
The Link will be different for each name, and it return by function: GetMyViewUrl,
input for this function is also a variable (changes from time to time).

So I tried this:

```
<a href='javascript:openpopup(<%#GetMyViewUrl(<%#Eval("compnId")%>))'><%#Eval("compnName1") %></a>
```

I got error:

```
CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line
```

So I tried to make it simpler:

```
<a href='javascript:openpopup(<%#GetMyViewUrl(<%#Eval("compnId")%>))'>SomeNames</a>
```

But same error.
So I guess it come from this part:

```
<%#GetMyViewUrl(<%#Eval("compnId")%>)
```

I suspect ascx cannot accept two of this go together?

How can I write it correctly here ?

Comment: try <%#GetMyViewUrl(Eval("compnId"))%> -  you can't nest the crocodile tags like that

Comment: I tried and it said: GetMyViewUrl(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: does the function expect an int? I think that eval returns a string?

Comment: So the way you put Eval("compnId") does not return correctly I think

Comment: No it expect string: protected string GetMyViewUrl(string compnyId)

Comment: Maybe add a breakpoint on GetMyViewUrl, run the debugger and see what value is being passed?

Comment: The page even can not load because of that error, so I cannot run debug until that line of code

Comment: Do you check for `null` or `empty string` for `CompnId` in the GetMyViewUrl method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within these `<%#  %>` you can have multiple `Eval` statements.

You need to start once with `<%#`. Try this:

```
<a href='<%# GetMyViewUrl(Eval("compnId").ToString()) %>'> SomeNames </a>
```

If you want to call a javascript function:

```
<a href=# onClick='javascript:openpopup(<%# GetMyViewUrl(Eval("compnId").ToString()) %>)'> SomeNames </a>
```

or

```
<a href='<%# GetMyViewUrl(Eval("compnId").ToString()) %>' target="_blank"> SomeNames </a>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to put into the javascript function. I put your answer in my code but I don't know why the javascript do not open the window.

Comment: Yes. I haven't noticed but still you don't need to call javascript function for opening window. If your method returns a valid URL then you need to specify `target` attribute only. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! But is there a grammar error here ? "CS1010: Newline in constant" when I use: <a href='<%# GetMyViewUrl(Eval("compnId1").ToString()) %'><%#Eval("compnName1") %></a>

Comment: Yes. href value should be in `' '` single quote start to end.